Debugging SOAP Request Errors in Postman for DataExchange Web Service
I am facing an issue while making a SOAP request to the DataExchange web service using Postman. I am getting a 500 Internal Server Error with the following error message:

The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver. Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).

Request Details:
URL: https://1.1.1.1/ews/dataexchange.svc
Method: POST
Authentication: Digest Authentication (Username and Password provided)
Headers:
Content-Type: application/soap+xml
SOAPAction: http://www.schneider-electric.com/common/dataexchange/2011/05/GetContainerItemsRequest
Body of the API look like this:
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns="http://www.schneider-electric.com/common/dataexchange/2011/05">
   <soap:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/addressing">
      <wsa:Action>http://www.schneider-electric.com/common/dataexchange/2011/05/GetContainerItemsRequest</wsa:Action>
      <wsa:To>https://10.154.2.75/ews/dataexchange.svc</wsa:To>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <ns:GetContainerItemsRequest>
         <!-- Include any necessary request parameters here -->
      </ns:GetContainerItemsRequest>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

Could you please help me understand the root cause of this issue and provide guidance on how to resolve it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
I tried various combinations for the XML body, but none of them are working—they always result in a 500 error.

Every Server is different so the the format of the request is different for every server.  So yo need to check the URL documentation to solve this issue.
